# View to show user relationships with different fields

Tags: 7, views, users

I am using the User Relationships module to allow users to forge relations between themselves. The relationship is 1 way of type Following. I have been able to do so. Now i want to create a view for the logged in user which would show him or her their pending relation request, the people they are following, and the people who follow them I tried to do so using Views and contextual filters and adding different fields but was unable to successfully do so. My use case is :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg78Z.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to first add a users view and then you add a contextual filter to the view using the user field that the relation will have now exposed in the contextual admin selection. Then add a default value of currently logged in user to the contextual filter and with that it will expose the relevant fields.

1. Add new view of type users
2. Add contextual filter of type user relationships: User who accepted the relationship
3. Add default value of logged in user
4. (optional but will expose even further info) add views relations to expose further data
5. profit

Comment: what do you mean by profit

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=profit